# Local Gitlab Container behind reverse proxy

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-ce

I want to run a GitLab instance using docker with docker compose behind an nginx reverse proxy. This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.6'
name: gitlab
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.24.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: gitlab_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx_confs:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx_certs:/etc/pki/nginx/gitlab
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'

  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.11.2-ce.0
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: gitlab_gitlab
    hostname: gitlab.myserver.local
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url 'https://gitlab.myserver.local'
        letsencrypt['enabled'] = false
         # Email
         gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_enabled'] = true
         gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'gitlab@myserver.ir'
         gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_display_name'] = 'My GitLab'
         # Reverse proxy nginx config
         nginx['listen_port'] = 9080
         nginx['listen_https'] = false
         nginx['proxy_set_headers'] = {
           "X-Forwarded-Proto" => "https",
           "X-Forwarded-Ssl" => "on",
           "Host" => "gitlab.myserver.local",
           "X-Real-IP" => "$$remote_addr",
           "X-Forwarded-For" => "$$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for",
           "Upgrade" => "$$http_upgrade",
           "Connection" => "$$connection_upgrade"
         }
    ports:
      - '2280:9080'
      - '2222:22'
    volumes:
      - ./gitlab_config:/etc/gitlab
      - ./gitlab_logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - ./gitlab_data:/var/opt/gitlab
    shm_size: '256m'
```

and also my nginx reverse proxy settings:

```
upstream git {
    server gitlab:9080;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name gitlab.myserver.local;

    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 3600s;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        # Websocket connection
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_pass http://git;
    }
}
```

when I run my compose file, and open the web page at `gitlab.myserver.local`, It redirects me to the `https://git/users/sign_in`. I don't have any SSL certificate so I want use http.